# When is monitor released in java

Tags: java, concurrency

If I have the code:

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition waiting = lock.newCondition();
```

Thread 1:

```
    value = default;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        waiting.await(new Long(timeout).longValue(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
```

Thread 2:

```
  lock.lock();
  //set value
  waiting.signalAll();
  lock.unlock();
```

Am I correct in that the monitor on the lock is released when await is called, allowing the event driven thread 2 to run if needed? If thread 2 happens to run, when will thread 1 be able to resume, upon signalAll(), or lock.unlock()? If thread 2 is signaling a wakeup, but still has a lock, how does that work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock is in fact released when invoking `await`.  When `signalAll` is called, no waiting threads will awake until the signalling thread `unlock`s

However, it is important to differentiate Java object monitors with Java Locks.  They are separate constructs, in fact the ReentrantLock/Condition itself can be a monitor in a different context then what you are working with (for example if instead of `await` you called `wait` you would get the obvious IllegalMonitorStateException).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess I mixed up the terminology a little bit between the old/new way- but it looks like its the same basic idea but one is using monitors and the other locks/conditions.

Comment: Thats true, those are 2 different mechanisms. Anyway, if you use monitors you should code your code inside a synchronized(monitor) block, so you won't have an IllegalMonitorStateException.

Comment: @WillDen You are right it is the same basic idea, and both `synchronized` and `ReentrantLock` have equivalent semantics.

Comment: why it is designed that `await` release the lock but `signal` does not? This is confusing to me.

Comment: @Jaskey because `signal` and `signalAll` does not suspend the thread.  When you invoke `signal` you're telling the JVM, when I  release the lock (which should be soon), let another thread waiting enter.  `await` will suspend the thread, and so gives you no opportunity to release the lock (which makes sense).